# To what ASCII codes are attached?

Tags: ascii, keyboard-events

Let's say I have **Q** letter in the top-left corner of my **QWERTY** keyboard and it has **81** ASCII code. On the **AZERTY** keyboard the top-left key is **A**. So if I click **A** on the **AZERTY** keyboard what code will be fired? Same *81* (if ASCII orients by the geographical key place) or 65 (if ASCII orients by the Latin letters)?

I am curious because I want my **WASD** keys (for character moving) to be placed in the same geographical place on any keyboard layout. How can I do that?

Comment: _"ASCII abbreviated from American Standard Code for Information Interchange, is a **character encoding standard for electronic communication**. **ASCII codes represent text** in computers, telecommunications equipment, and other devices. Most modern character-encoding schemes are based on ASCII, although they support many additional characters."_ (Source: [ASCII - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII))

Comment: You can have an options screen with button config. But if you start your game with an obvious need to walk upwards, detect which of W or Z the user presses and make an educated guess as to their keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am curious because I want my WASD keys (for character moving) to be placed in the same geographical place on any keyboard layout. How can I do that?

Your best bet is probably to offer a configuration stage where the end use chooses the keys they want to use. That way, you not only support different keyboard layouts, but left- and right-handed people, people with disabilities who may prefer a different arrangement, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can u please help me with another problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679350/how-to-find-out-event-key-from-event-code)?

Answer (score 2):

ASCII encodes letters and not keyboard keys for this reason symbol A is encoded by 81 number no matter where the key is on the keyboard layout.
Some operation systems will allow you to map keys or have special software for that purpose but to give a concrete answer we need more details about your setup (hardware, software, OS e.t.c)

Comment: Keycodes are not bind to ASCII or any other character coding system, they are just mapped codes for the keyboard, and may vary depending on the manufacturer and the keyboard type. For example, numebr 0 on the top row has usually the keycode 48, but number 0 in the number block is 96.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I feel like your comment could be a different answer, addressing some implied confusion in the original question. While my answer answers the question directly you go one step deeper and help to ask the correct question.