# How to find out event.key from event.code

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

Recently I heard about [new ways](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/03/internationalize-your-keyboard-controls/) of working with various keyboards, using *KeyboardEvent.code* and *KeyboardEvent.key*. It's a great feature but is there a way of getting **event.key** when you know **event.code**?

Let's say that the user printed 'w' letter and triggered an event with event.code = **'KeyW'** that you saved somewhere. Then later you need to find out the **event.key** value that the user would print if he triggered that event again (with event.code = **'KeyW'**). Maybe I should programatically trigger key pressing somehow?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="demo">asd</p>
  <script>

window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDownHandler, false);

let key_code = undefined;    

function KeyDownHandler(event) {
  let key_code = event.code;
  console.log(key_code);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = key_code;
}
    
function CodeToKey(key_code)
{
  // I want this function to be able to translate 'KeyW' to 'w'
}

  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try to use a package as https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycode, but as I understand from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code it can change per layout and that's why event.key is better to use

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]